# Remove recurrent event from .ics

Tags: outlook, icalendar, ical.net

I'm using iCal.net to generate ICS files which are then send via Email. This works perfectly, and the events are properly imported when I click on the ICS file in the attachment.

However, I also want to be able to remove the already imported recurrent events before they are imported. I'm working with an opt-in/opt-out system where users can select days they want to have events on.

So either I need to update the already imported recurrent events, or delete them and re-import.

Right now I'm using this to create the recurrent event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20210104T151500
DTSTAMP:20210105T105450Z
DTSTART:20210104T150000
LOCATION:Online
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=99991231T235959;BYDAY=4MO,4WE
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Recurrent event
UID:e39bd24c-1a7f-4eb4-8174-af69d7cd77a7
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And I am trying to delete the events with:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
METHOD:CANCEL
DTEND:20210104T151500
DTSTAMP:20210105T105450Z
DTSTART:20210104T150000
LOCATION:Online
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=99991231T235959;BYDAY=4TU,4FR
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Recurrent event
UID:e39bd24c-1a7f-4eb4-8174-af69d7cd77a7
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

OR (because deleting isn't working, I need options :D) update the existing event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20210104T151500
DTSTAMP:20210105T105450Z
DTSTART:20210104T150000
LOCATION:Online
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=99991231T235959;BYDAY=4TU,4FR
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Recurrent event
UID:e39bd24c-1a7f-4eb4-8174-af69d7cd77a7
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The cancel
UID's are the same, I have tried with a recurrent-id with DTSTART value.

I have also tried below links:
[How to delete a single event from a recurring set using ical programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507030/how-to-delete-a-single-event-from-a-recurring-set-using-ical-programmatically)
[How to cancel an calendar event using ics files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551764/how-to-cancel-an-calendar-event-using-ics-files)
And more like these.

Comment: If one wants to be able to update events by updating the ics file, it is best if one gets people to subscribe to a .ics URL, their own personal .ics url.   

Importing events tends to make the events in the file look like 'own' events and also relies on the individual actually taking action to click on the cancel one. WHEREAS if they have subscribed to a .ics url, it will automatically update.     Trying to cancel by relying on the receiver person clicking on the ics is unreliable.   In addition receiving applications may have inconsistent handling of importation of  (same UID) events

Comment: Note also that your BYDAY is different between your original UID and the one you say you want to cancel with. BYDAY=4MO,4WE  vs BYDAY=4TU,4FR.    AT the very least the RRULES must be exactly the same.